# nestjs + vscode - debugging problem since adding typeorm

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, nestjs, typeorm

I'm starting a new nestjs project.
Everything worked fine untill I added typeorm.  Since then the program exits without warning in debug mode, still works fine when run from the CLI.
The `test` debug message from `main.ts` is displayed in debug mode, after that the debugged disconnects.
Any hints on how to debug this ?

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
      "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"
      ],
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy",
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "PORT": "3000",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**main.ts**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';


async function bootstrap() {
  const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3000');
  console.log('test');
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(port);
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
}

bootstrap();
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppController } from './controllers/app.controller';
import { AppService } from './services/app.service';
import { PasswordService } from './services/passwords.service';
import { RebootController } from './controllers/reboot.controller';
import { PasswordController } from './controllers/password.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { UserController } from './controllers/user.controller';

import config from './config/config';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, load: [config] }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get('database'),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
    RebootController,
    PasswordController,
    UserController,
  ],
  providers: [AppService, PasswordService, UserService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Output from the `nest start` command**

```
test
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +24ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +185ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RoutesResolver] AppController {}: +5ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {, GET} route +4ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RoutesResolver] RebootController {/reboot}: +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/reboot, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RoutesResolver] PasswordController {/password}: +0ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/password/create/:length?, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RoutesResolver] UserController {/user}: +0ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/getAll, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 22652   - 2020-07-16 12:47:55   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
listening on port 3000
```

Comment: Turns out the problem arises from adding `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])` to the imports in `app.module.ts`